# How to model a warehouse application with DDD/CQRS/ES?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

We want to model a warehouse application. Let us assume we identified the following real world objects:

- Articles(the things stored in the warehouse)
- Palettes (where the Articles are on)
- Compartments (the places in the racks where the palettes are stored in)

There are the following constraints:

- A palette is in exactly one compartment
- A compartment can hold zero or one palette

For the start we have one operation:

- Move (moves a palette from its current compartment to another).

Of course this is very simplified.

How should this be modelled?

Stockitem could be a value object I think. One solution would be to model the whole warehouse as an aggregate with palette and compartment entities. The move operation could be implemented without any problems in this case regarding its constraints (invariants). But this approach has obvious drawbacks. The Event log for this aggregate will grow infinitely. Two move operations could not be executed in parallel because of the aggregate versioning and so on. And from a ddd point of view, it feels not right for me.

Another approach would be to make each palette and each compartment its own aggregate. But how would the move operation be implemented then?

**Problem 1 : Who loads referenced aggregates?**

I think it should stick to the palette. The palette could reference the compartment it is in (its an aggregat). But how is this reference implemented (CQRS/ES)? The Comandhandler of the move command obviously will load the palette aggregate from the palette repository and call the move method on it. Who loads the referenced compartment? And who loads the compartment it should be moved to? I read that aggregates should not access repositories. Should the commandhandler load both compartments? Should the compartments be given to the move method as parameters? Or should the commandhandler set the current compartment to the palette and give the target compartment as a parameter?

**Problem 2 & 3 : Constraints and bidirectional association between aggregates**

What about the constraints? To check if the target compartment is empty, the compartment needs to know the palette that is stored in it. This would be a bidirectional association that should be avoided. And because they are different aggregates, they could not be updated in the same transaction. Has the palette to fire a domain event to inform the compartment that it will move to it? Has it to be implemented as a saga with undo action? What if two moves conflict, one wins, but the loosing palette could not be moved back, because the old compartment is filled up in the meantime?

This all seems very complicated to me regarding the really simple problem.

In the books and the examples it seems all so clear. But if I try to use it, I seem to do it wrong.

Could somebody guide me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1**

I think you need to do some transactional analysis in addition to the business analysis here.

If your domain is highly collaborative (which is what DDD is recommended for), how often do moves to a given compartment happen ? Would it be feasible contention-wise for the Move operation to happen under a transaction that spans across the 2 `Compartment` aggregates (source and target) ? Or would eventual consistency suffice, where the source Compartment would signal the world via an event that the Palette has left it, and the target Compartment would somehow be informed later, in an asynchronous way, that the Palette is joining it ?

A palette floating "in limbo" for a small amount of time can be perfectly acceptable, that's something you need to ask a domain expert about.

**Problem 2**

A bidirectional association is not the only solution. You could ask the `PaletteRepository` for all the Palettes that have CompartmentID X. Alternatively, Compartment could (should) have a list of Palette IDs, not a full reference to them.

Overall, I think you should look first if there's a business implication/answer to all the design questions you're asking yourself. The domain expert will usually have an educated opinion on whether eventual consistency is realistic or immediate consistency is required, what should happen in case of conflict, etc.

Comment: The problem with the second solution is that you still can't enforce that a `Compartment` doesn't hold more than one `Palette` or vice-versa depending on the relation side. I'm often wondering if it's ok to just rely on DB constraints to enforce these rules. For instance, if you hold `compartmentId` on `Palette` and perform `palette.moveTo(compartment)` you can effectively be sure that the palette will ever have just one compartment, but not that the compartment has a single palette. Relying on DB constraints to enforce that rule however is trivial and allows you to be strongly consistent.

Comment: @plalx I think I'd prefer this invariant to be explicit in the code and enforce it in `Compartment`, either thanks to its internal Palette count, or if it doesn't have it, someone has to pass it around (or `Compartment` could call the Repo directly to get it)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this. So you think the "saga" solution with eventually consistency would be the right way? The other part of my Problem 1 question was, who loads the needed aggregates. I will clarify this question a little bit.

Comment: As your answer to Problem 2, if I use (cqrs with) event sourcing, there is no easy way to query the repository for all palettes that have compartmentid x. This would be only possible with the read model (a projection that holds this information). But how can an aggregate of the write model get information from a projection of the read model?

Comment: I don't think there is *one* right way, as I explained, only you can tell which way suits your domain better :)

Comment: Yes, Aggregates are loaded by Command Handlers and they (or their ID's) can be passed to other aggregates methods. If you think it's not safe to ask the Query Side for Palettes with a given CompartmentID, then you should definitely implement it on the write side as a has-a relationship inside `Compartment`. My guess is that whatever aggregate is in charge of enforcing the uniqueness should also possess the data.

Comment: @guillaume31 I know what a Saga is, but never actually implemented one yet (never really applied DDD in real world yet). Could you explain what could be the process flow with a Saga? The thing that eludes me is how to know if the `Compartment` got changed while we called `palette.moveTo(comp)`? When the `PaletteMoved` event will be processed to bring the `Comparment` consistent and the compartment already holds a palette, how to know if the palette was already there before processing the operation and we meant to replace it or a concurrency conflict occurred.

Comment: @guillaume31 Would you add `replacedPaletteId = compartment.palette().id()` to the PaletteMoved event (considering it's already holding a palette) so that you know if it changed? I'm a bit puzzled on how to correctly handle this one without introducing technical concerns to the model.

Comment: @plalx As I understood the domain, there is no "replace palette", so it can only be a concurrency conflict. The target Compartment can raise an event to notify that a conflict occured. I guess that if ReplacePalette existed, you would have the choice between caring and not caring about the replaced palette and maybe add some data to the event indeed. Once again, this is all domain analysis !

Comment: @plalx I haven't implemented complex sagas per se either, only "simple" eventual consistency cases, but you have an example here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591569.aspx

Comment: @guillaume31 Ok I see what you mean. I'll have a look at the article. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should just start object modeling the behaviour, and don't think about aggregates and value objects at all. Once you've modeled the needed behaviour, you'll know what are the entities, aggregates, roots and value objects.

In the explanations by [Vaughn Vernon](http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/) he makes it clear that you need to work out the details of what you need before you can make these decisions.

Comment: You are right of course. The only behaviour in my example is the move method. What are the entities and aggregates regarding this? And part of my problem is that its not a pure ddd question, but also about implementation details regarding the use of cqrs/es.

Comment: As long as you don't add more than this move, a single aggregate is fine. Physical movement is slow, so who cares about parallel moves, just serialize them. More behavior, we want more behavior!